# How is scipy.stats.multivariate_normal.pdf different from the same function written using numpy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, scipy, probability

I need to use the multivariate normal distribution in a script. I have noticed that my version of it gives a different answer from scipy's method. I can't really figure out why...

Here is my function:

```
def gauss(x, mu, sigma):
    assert np.linalg.det(sigma)!=0, "determinant of sigma is 0"
    y = np.exp((-1/2)*(x-mu).T.dot(np.linalg.inv(sigma)).dot(x-mu))/np.sqrt(
      np.power(2*np.pi, len(x))*np.linalg.det(sigma)
    )
    return y
```

Here is a comparison of the results:

```
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-0.54849176, 6.39530657])
mu = np.array([15,20])
sigma = np.array([
  [2,3],
  [4,10]
])

print(gauss(x, mu, sigma))
# output is 1.8781656851138248e-37

print(multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mu, sigma))
# output is 2.698549423643947e-61
```

Has anybody noticed this? Is my function wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `(x-mu).T` does not do what you think it does when `x` and `mu` are 1D arrays. Use `reshape(1, -1)` if you want to be safe.

Comment: Also, instead of asserting arrayness, convert to array without extra copies. That's actually pretty standard.

Comment: @MadPhysicist thanks for the comments. I tried `reshape(1, -1)` but it didn't seem to help

Comment: I'll play with it and let you know when I get to a desktop

Comment: The densities are incredibly low, so a priori, one might guess that all you're seeing are numerical issues: Setting a pair of parentheses differently would be enough to cause the discrepancy. However, something else is going on here as you also have a discrepancy for `x = np.array([15.054849176, 20.39530657])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The particular input you've used as an example could be slightly misleading because the values are so low that numerical issues would easily suffice to cause the discrepancy you are seeing. However, even when using an example with larger densities, you will still have issues:

```py
In [95]: x = np.array([15.00054849176, 20.0009530657]) 
    ...: mu = np.array([15, 20]) 
    ...: sigma = np.array([ 
    ...:   [2, 3], 
    ...:   [4, 10] 
    ...: ]) 
    ...:                                                                                        

In [96]: print(gauss(x, mu, sigma)) 
    ...: print(multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mu, sigma)) 
    ...:                                                                                        
0.05626976565965294
0.07957746514880353
```

Perhaps interestingly, the discrepancy is a factor of `np.sqrt(2)` up to numerical issues, but this is a bit of a red herring: as it turns out, the discrepancy is caused simply by your covariance matrix not being a covariance matrix: While it's positive semi-definite, it's *not symmetric*. Using a valid input, the two approaches will indeed agree (up to numerical issues):

```py
In [99]: x = np.array([15.00054849176, 20.0009530657]) 
    ...: mu = np.array([15, 20]) 
    ...: sigma = np.array([ 
    ...:   [2, 3], 
    ...:   [3, 10] 
    ...: ]) 
    ...:                                                                                        

In [100]: print(gauss(x, mu, sigma)) 
     ...: print(multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mu, sigma)) 
     ...:                                                                                       
0.047987017204594515
0.04798701720459451
```

Or, with your original inputs:

```
In [111]: x = np.array([-0.54849176, 6.39530657]) 
     ...: mu = np.array([15, 20]) 
     ...: sigma = np.array([ 
     ...:   [2, 3], 
     ...:   [3, 10] 
     ...: ]) 
     ...:                                                                                       

In [112]: print(gauss(x, mu, sigma)) 
     ...: print(multivariate_normal.pdf(x, mu, sigma)) 
     ...:                                                                                       
5.060725651214228e-32
5.060725651214157e-32
```

Comment: Correct! I should have mentioned in my question that I did try to use x as my mean to get the highest probability and I still saw a discrepancy. And I did try the identity matrix as the covariance, which makes both outputs the same. But as soon as I changed it the discrepancy was back!

Comment: Great; if the answer was helpful, you can [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer); besides providing me with artificial internet points, this helps users identify which questions are still in need of an answer.